# Do I have to buy Minecraft on the ps4 if I have it on xbox

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought Minecraft on my xbox and wondered if i can use my account to play on my PlayStation.

Answer (score 1):

Buying a game will sometimes let you play it on multiple consoles made by that company, depending on the game.  As far as I know though, there has never been a case where buying it on one company's store lets you download it for free on another company's store.  Buying a X-Box game will never let you play it for free on the Playstation, you have to buy it on both if you want to play it on both.